# WebDriver: find element by CSSSelector or XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have a problem to get element `<i class="angle-up"></i>` on the following page. The selection should be depended on `"data-id"` value. Thanks in advance.

```
<li class="recent" data-to="3" data-off="23" data-id="5">
    <a class="collapse in" href="/board">
        <span>
            Board
        </span>
        <i class="angle-up"></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="" data-to="3" data-off="23" data-id="7">
    <a class="collapse in" href="/set">
        <span>
           Set
        </span>
        <i class="angle-up"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think if the value is data-id dependant then you might need to split the Xpath or Css selector in 3 parts as below:

> Part1=//li[@data_id='
>
> Part2= (Fetch this value at runtime using an appropriate variable)
>
> Part3= ']//i[@class='angle-up']

and now you may use the following code to use the element

```
    public class TestElement {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(YOUR INTERNAL URL HERE.);
       
        String elementPart1=//li[@data_id='
        String elementPart2=5       //keeping the id you are looking for
        String elementPart3=']//i[@class='angle-up']

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementPart1+elementPart2+elementPart3);
      
    }
}
```

Here as you may see one example of such xpath could be

```
//li[@data_id='5']//i[@class='angle-up']
```

Also if I would advise you to check using [firefinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/) which is a [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) extension to verify that the xpath is correct.